# How to set slippage in web3js

Tags: web3js, ether, ethers.js, bsc

I'm trying to buy a token through web3js, I can buy tokens with low slippage, however any token that has slippage is failing.

this what I got:

```
let amountOutMin = '1';


let router = new web3.eth.Contract(pancakeswapRouterAbi,
    PANCAKESWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS,
    {from: address});

let txData = router.methods.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
    web3.utils.toHex(amountOutMin),
    [BNB_TOKEN_ADDRESS, tokenAddress],
    address,
    web3.utils.toHex(Math.round(Date.now() / 1000) + buyTimeout)
);

let buyNonce = await getAccountNonce();

let rawTransaction = {
    'from': address,
    'gasPrice': web3.utils.toHex(buyGasPrice),
    'gasLimit': web3.utils.toHex(buyGasLimit),
    'to': PANCAKESWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS,
    'value': web3.utils.toHex(bnbAmountInWei),
    'data': txData.encodeABI(),
    'nonce': web3.utils.toHex(buyNonce)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Slippage is not a property of a token, so it is not correct to say "...any toke that has slippage...". Slippage is simply when the bid/ask spread changes between the time a market order is requested and the time an exchange or other market-maker executes the order.

With that cleared up, I suspect that your `amountOutMin` in your `txData` is causing the transaction to fail, as the prices moves below this value. If you wanted to simulated slippage, you could multiply this number by a percentage (your slippage percentage).

```
let tradeAmount = 1;
let slippagePercentage = 0.2
let amountOutMin = tradeAmount - (tradeAmount * slippagePercentage)
let amountOutMax = tradeAmount + (tradeAmount * slippagePercentage) // if applicable
```

Comment: I set the amountAoutMin to 0, and it throws PancakeRouter: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT.